# Kestrel is not loading interop DLLL

Tags: f#, com-interop, kestrel

I have an F# Giraffe application using Kestrel.  I am referencing an external DLL via a COM typelib, which generates a DLL named Interop.PCDCLientLib.  I added a build event to copy that DLL into the $(OutDir), and I can see it in the proper directory "bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0".   The DLL is properly loaded in unit tests.  However, when I run the application, I get an error: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.PCDCLIENTLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

I am trying to find if there is a another runtime directory to copy the DLL into so that it can be loaded.  Where else should it go?

Comment: You procmon from systinternals https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon filter by files and your process name, and you will see where it looks

Comment: I was able to make this work by setting "Embed Interop Types" to false in the Interop.PCDClientLib.dll properties.

Comment: You should answer yourself if you found a solution and are happy with it